# Implicit Operators and lambdas

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, expression, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to create a class that takes a lambda and stores it internally. The syntax would be something like:

```
class Lambda<TIn, TOut> {
    private Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expr;
    private Func<TIn, TOut>> func;

    public Lambda(Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> e) {
        expr = e;
    }

    public Lambda(Func<TIn, TOut> f) {
        func = f;
    }

    public static implicit operator Lambda<TIn, TOut>([lambdatype] o) {
        return new Lambda(o);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Lambda<TIn, TOut> l = o => ... ;
```

But I'm having some trouble figuring out the details. I know that a lambda is an anon type until it's assigned to either an expression or a delegate and that I would (I believe) have to use an implicit operator to get the syntax I'm going for, but beyond that I've hit a wall. I can use Expression or Func in my implicit operator if they've already been assigned to a variable like so:

```
Expression<Func<T1, T2>> e = o => ...;
Func<T1, T2> f = o => ...;

Lambda<T1, T2> l1 = e, l2 = f;
```

But I'd much prefer to just assign the lambda itself and have the class figure out the details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that the C# language [does not chain user-defined implicit conversions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/04/16/chained-user-defined-explicit-conversions-in-c.aspx).

Lambda expressions are untyped expressions that have implicit conversions to the (potentially infinite) set of compatible delegate & expression tree types.  (see §6.5 of the spec)

You cannot invoke both that implicit conversion and the user-defined implicit conversion from a delegate type to your own type implicitly.

Instead, you can explicitly create a typed delegate:

```
Lambda<TIn, TOut> l = new Func<TIn, TOUt>(o => ... );
```

You could also ask the C# language team to define a syntax for user-defined implicit conversions from method groups or lambdas to any type.

Comment: Ahh, I was hoping to avoid that :( Ok, well thanks for the reply!

Comment: @SLaks - I am trying to write implicit operators for type conversion. Totally doable from explicit types, but I am trying to abstract the operators to a base type (ex. BaseViewModel<TModel, TViewModel> ) on which the operators could be placed. That even possible or just a pipe dream for a yellow belt programmer? If it is worthy of a separate question, let me know and I'll post one.

Comment: @SLaks - or an interface if possible... just something that forces the operators to be implemented for type conversion... in this scenario, the `TViewModel` class inheriting from `BaseViewModel`, be forced to implement the operators and define the conversion (ex. `this.Prop1 = that.Prop1;`)

Answer (score 0):

When you actually define the lambda expression it needs to be explicit (like an `Action` or Func ect). If you do that you can just assign directly to a property of type delegate.

```
 public class myClass
 {
     public Delegate myDelegate { get; set; }

     public myClass(Delegate d)
     {
         myDelegate = d;
     }
 }


 myClass myInstance = new myClass(new Func<int, int>(x => x * x));
```